# How to open projects from VS 2019 in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio

At home, I have Visual Studio Community 2019 installed on my pc while in school, we use 2012. When the teacher gave us an activity, I decided to do it at home but found I am unable to open it when I brought it to school. Is there a way for me to open my projects from my later version of VS in the previous version of Vs in my school?

If it's relevant, we're just exploring the most basic of functions and at the moment, it's just on Windows Forms

Comment: It's usually possible to convert projects from older versions of VS to new versions, but not  the opposite way. You might consider using meta-build tools like CMake which can create workspace solutions and projects for multiple build systems and environments, including many versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Relevant documentation page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2019&preserve-view=true